# Debug Assertion Failed! With Invalid null pointer error

Tags: c++, string, visual-c++

I compiled my code just fine without any errors. However, when I try to run the program a window pops up with these contents:

```
Program: C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\MSVCP120D.dll
File: c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 12.0\vc\include\xstring
Line: 1168
Expression: invalid null pointer
```

I'm not sure what the problem is or what it could possibly be. I know with absolute certainty the header is perfectly fine as it was provided by the professor and we are not to touch it.

**INTENT**

The intent of the code is to take a binary input from the user and display a decimal equivalent. Then take decimal input and print it out as a binary number.

**CODE**

Main

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "LinkedStack.h"
#include <string>
#include <math.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>

using namespace std;

int main(){

    string binaryNum = "0";     // Holds the entered binary value
    string decResult = "0";     // Holds the decimal result
    int binResult = 0, pow = 1; // Holds the binary result and the power of 1 for conversion
    int decimal = 0;            // Holds the entered decimal value
    int decimalRootVal;         // Holds the decimal value for description later on

    // Initialize stack
    linkedStackType<string> binaryStack;

    cout << "Please enter a binary number starting from the left." << endl; // Takes user input to convert binary into decimal
    cout << "Binary Value: ";
    cin >> binaryNum;                                                       // Takes input and assigns it to an int 
    binaryStack.push(binaryNum);                                            // Pushes binaryNum into the stack
    for (int i = binaryNum.length() - 1; i >= 0; pow <<= 1, --i){           // Binary to decimal conversion
        binResult += (binaryNum[i] - '0') * pow;
    }
    cout << "Decimal equivalent of " << binaryNum << ": " << binResult << endl; // Prints the decimal equivalent of binaryNum
    binaryStack.pop(binaryNum);                                                 // Empties the stack

    cout << "What is the decimal you wish to be turned into binary? ";      // Asks for user input of a decimal
    cin >> decimal;
    decimalRootVal = decimal;                                               // Shown to the user later on for description

    while (decimal > 0){                                                    // Decimal to binary conversion
        decResult += (decimal & 1) ? "1" : "0";
        decimal >>= 1;
        binaryStack.push(decResult);                                        // Pushes the binary value for each placement into the stack
    }

    cout << "Binary equivalent of " << decimalRootVal << ": " << decResult << endl;

    binaryStack.destroyStack();// Destroys the stack 
}
```

Header

```
#ifndef H_StackType
#define H_StackType

#include <iostream>
#include "stdafx.h"

//Definition of the node
template <class Type>
struct nodeType{

    Type info;
    nodeType<Type> *link;
};

template<class Type>
class linkedStackType{
public:
    const linkedStackType<Type>& operator = (const linkedStackType<Type>&);// Overload the assignment operator
    void initializeStack(); // Initialize the stack to an empty state. 
    // Post: Stack elements are removed; top = NULL
    bool isEmptyStack();// Function returns true if the stack is empty; 
    // Otherwise, it returns false
    bool isFullStack(); // Function returns true if the stack is full;
    // Otherwise, it returns false
    void push(const Type& newItem); // Add the newItem to the stack.
    // Pre condition: stack exists and is not full
    // Post condition: stack is changed and the newItem is added to the top of stack. 
    // top points to the updated stack
    void pop(Type& poppedElement);  // Remove the top element of the stack.
    // Pre condition: Stack exists and is not empty.
    // Post condition: stack is changed and the top element is removed from the stack. 
    // The top element of the stack is saved in poppedElement
    void destroyStack();// Remove all elements of the stack, leaving the stack in an empty state.
    // Post condition: top = NULL
    linkedStackType();// Default constructor; Post condition: top = NULL
    linkedStackType(const linkedStackType<Type>& otherStack);// Copy constructor
    ~linkedStackType();// Destructor; All elements of the stack are removed from the stack

private:
    nodeType<Type> *top;// Pointer to the stack
};

template<class Type>// Default constructor
linkedStackType<Type>::linkedStackType(){
    top = NULL;
}

template<class Type>
void linkedStackType<Type>::destroyStack(){

    nodeType<Type> *temp;       // Pointer to delete the node

    while (top != NULL){        // While there are elements in the stack

        temp = top;             // Set temp to point to the current node
        top = top->link;        // Advance top to the next node
        delete temp;            // Deallocate memory occupied by temp
    }
}

template<class Type>
void linkedStackType<Type>::initializeStack(){
    destroyStack();
}

template<class Type>
bool linkedStackType<Type>::isEmptyStack(){
    return(top == NULL);
}

template<class Type>
bool linkedStackType<Type>::isFullStack(){
    return 0;
}

template<class Type>
void linkedStackType<Type>::push(const Type& newElement){

    nodeType<Type> *newNode;        // Pointer to create the new node

    newNode = new nodeType<Type>;   // Create the node
    newNode->info = newElement;     // Store newElement in the node
    newNode->link = top;            // Insert newNode before top
    top = newNode;                  // Set top to point to the top node
}

template<class Type>
void linkedStackType<Type>::pop(Type& poppedElement){

    nodeType<Type> *temp;           // Pointer to deallocate memory

    poppedElement = top->info;      // Copy the top element into poppedElement
    temp = top;                     // Set temp to point to the top node
    top = top->link;                // Advance top to the next node
    delete temp;                    // Delete the top node
}

template<class Type>// Copy constructor
linkedStackType<Type>::linkedStackType(const linkedStackType<Type>& otherStack){

    nodeType<Type> *newNode, *current, *last;

    if (otherStack.top == NULL)
        top = NULL;
    else{
        current = otherStack.top;   // Set current to point to the stack to be copied

        // Copy the top element of the stack 
        top = new nodeType<Type>;   // Create the node
        top->info = current->info;  // Copy the info
        top->link = NULL;           // Set the link field of the node to null
        last = top;                 // Set last to point to the node
        current = current->link;    // Set current to point to the next node

        // Copy the remaining stack
        while (current != NULL){

            newNode = new nodeType<Type>;
            newNode->info = current->info;
            newNode->link = NULL;
            last->link = newNode;
            last = newNode;
            current = current->link;
        }
    }
}

template<class Type>// Destructor
linkedStackType<Type>::~linkedStackType(){

    nodeType<Type> *temp;

    while (top != NULL){    // While there are elements in the stack

        temp = top;         // Set temp to point to the current node
        top = top->link;    // Advance first to the next node
        delete temp;        // Deallocate the memory occupied by temp
    }
}

template<class Type>// Overloading the assignment operator
const linkedStackType<Type>& linkedStackType<Type>::operator = (const linkedStackType<Type>& otherStack){
    nodeType<Type> *newNode, *current, *last;

    if (this != &otherStack){           // Avoid self-copy
        if (top != NULL)                // If the stack is not empty, destroy it
            destroyStack();

        if (otherStack.top == NULL)
            top = NULL;
        else{
            current = otherStack.top;   // Set current to point to the stack to be copied

            // Copy the top element of otherStack 
            top = new nodeType<Type>;   // Create the node
            top->info = current->info;  // Copy the info
            top->link = NULL;           // Set the link field of the node to null
            last = top;                 // Make last point to the node
            current = current->link;    // Make current point to the next node

            // Copy the remaining elements of the stack
            while (current != NULL){

                newNode = new nodeType<Type>;
                newNode->info = current->info;
                newNode->link = NULL;
                last->link = newNode;
                last = newNode;
                current = current->link;
            }
        }
    }
    return *this;
}
#endif
```

Comment: Debug your code step by step. In this way you'll find where it fails.

Comment: May come from your implementation of "LinkedStack"

Comment: Does `binaryStack.pop(decResult)` overwrite the contents of `decResult` where you just put your result?

Comment: @PengZhang I added the header file. I don't believe there is an error due to it being from the professor and we can't alter it.

Comment: @KhouriGiordano I don't believe that is the issue but I've updated code so I can show the header and missing `cout` statement for the decResult

Comment: string binaryNum = 0; You cannot construct a string from integer!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are many problems in your code.

**First of all**, the NULL pointer error comes from

```
string binaryNum = 0;
```

There is no constructor of `string` which takes an integer. If you want the string be `"0"`, use `string x("0");`

**Second**, your code converting from binary to decimal is wrong.

```
for (int i = binaryNum.length() - 1; i >= 0; pow <<= 1){
    binResult += (binaryNum[i] - '0');
}
```

Where is `pow` used? Where is `i` decremented? There is an infinite loop if `binaryNum` has length larger than 1. Change it to

```
for (int i = binaryNum.length() - 1; i >= 0; pow <<= 1, --i){
    binResult += (binaryNum[i] - '0')*pow;
}
```

**Third**, your code converting from decimal to binary is wrong. Make the following changes.

add `#include <algorithm>`

```
//decResult = to_string(decimal); comment this line!
binaryStack.push(decResult);

while(decimal>0){
    decResult += (decimal & 1)?"1":"0";
    decimal>>=1;
}
reverse(decResult.begin(), decResult.end());
```

Comment: Thank very much for your help. You are completely correct. I should have caught basic things like this before I even posted. However, `reverse(decResult.begin(), decResult.end());` doesn't need to be used for the binary number to be printed correctly.

Answer (score 1):

This is not a valid way to initialize a string:

```
string binaryNum = 0;
```

If you want an empty string:

```
string binaryNum;
```

If you want a string containing a zero:

```
string binaryNum = "0";
```